# No write permissions on /usr/local/* | Mac OS X 10.15 Catalina

Tags: terminal, catalina, homebrew, permission

### I have problems with write perms in /usr/local/(lib|Cellar|include|etc.) folders

[This](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) material says that admin user have write perms in `/usr/local`, but I have problems with installing through make, brew, npm and simple copying. `sudo chown` doesn't work too.

*Disabling SIP looks like a solution, but I don't want to keep it off permanently because of security reasons.*
Here is some screenshots:

**cmake installing**: `sudo make install`
[image]

**brew installing and sudo chown**
[image]

**npm -g installing**
[image]

**`sudo ls -dleO /usr/local /usr/local/*`:**

```
drwxr-xr-x   17 root     wheel  sunlnk      544 17 сен 15:05 /usr/local
drwxrwxrwx    2 502      admin  restricted   64 19 ноя  2019 /usr/local/Caskroom
drwxrwxrwx   40 502      admin  restricted 1280 21 июн 20:20 /usr/local/Cellar
drwxrwxrwx    4 502      admin  restricted  128 19 ноя  2019 /usr/local/Frameworks
drwxrwxrwx   20 kotofey  wheel  -           640 21 июн 20:14 /usr/local/Homebrew
drwxrwxrwx    7 kotofey  wheel  -           224  3 июн 13:36 /usr/local/MacGPG2
drwxrwxrwx  187 502      admin  restricted 5984 22 июн 13:45 /usr/local/bin
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     wheel  -            96 17 сен 15:05 /usr/local/doc
drwxrwxrwx   10 502      admin  restricted  320 19 ноя  2019 /usr/local/etc
drwxrwxrwx   66 502      admin  restricted 2112 19 ноя  2019 /usr/local/include
drwxrwxrwx  138 502      admin  restricted 4416 19 ноя  2019 /usr/local/lib
drwxrwxrwx   52 502      admin  restricted 1664 21 июн 20:20 /usr/local/opt
drwxrwxrwx    9 502      admin  restricted  288 19 ноя  2019 /usr/local/sbin
drwxrwxrwx   22 502      admin  restricted  704 19 ноя  2019 /usr/local/share
drwxr-xr-x    4 kotofey  wheel  -           128 11 сен 12:57 /usr/local/texlive
drwxrwxrwx    4 502      admin  restricted  128 19 ноя  2019 /usr/local/var
```

Comment: @nohillside I had updated question, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you restore the system from a backup or migrate it in the past?

Comment: @nohillside no, laptop is three month old